# Does it make sense to regard the graph of any function as being a "sort-of-null set"?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Following the nice answer to [Do the Lebesgue-null sets cover "all the sets can naturally be regarded as sort-of-null sets"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272603/do-the-lebesgue-null-sets-cover-all-the-sets-can-naturally-be-regarded-as-sort), the particular situation that I am especially interested in (which is a kind of "advanced version" of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35606/lebesgue-measure-of-the-graph-of-a-function) is:

Let $F$ be the set of bijective Borel-measurable functions $f \colon [0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1] \times [0,1]$ that preserve the Lebesgue measure.

> > 1. Is it the case that for any sequence $(K_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of functions $K_n \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ and any sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $F$, the set
> >        $$ B \ := \ \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n(\mathrm{graph}\,K_n) $$
> >        does not contain a set of positive Lebesgue measure?
> > 2. If the answer to the above is *yes*: what if we allow the functions $K_n$ to be set-valued functions, with $K_n(x)$ being a Lebesgue-null subset of $[0,1]$ for all $x \in [0,1]$?

[Intuitive motivation: Under suitable conditions, the "disintegration theorem" allows one to regard a measure on a product space $X \times Y$ as an $X$-based random measure on $Y$. From this point of view, one might wish to regard a set whose $Y$-sections are null (under the disintegrated measure) as being itself "effectively null" under the original measure; but if the answers to the above questions are *no*, then we cannot really do this.]

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836856/covering-mathbb-r2-with-function-graphs

Comment: (Okay, I now see that the answer given there assumes CH, but that's okay.)

Comment: Davies' proof does not use CH. The reference is Davies, Roy O., Covering the plane with denumerably many curves, J. London Math. Soc. 38 1963, 433–438